# Is there any way to call C++ function from Python?

Tags: python, c++

I'm new to Python. Is there a way to use C++ libraries while coding in Python?

What technique should be used to perform this task?

Comment: Here is an exhaustive documentation covering how to call C++ functions - https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html

Comment: thanks a lot. should i close the question?

Comment: Yes, you can close the question.

Comment: @hellboy Please give answer, user40 if you are agree with answer please mark it as accepted and please don't close this question this will help someone in future.

Comment: You can refer to this [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145270/calling-c-c-from-python).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may refer this [documentation link](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html) to get the details on how to call C++ functions from Python.

Answer (score 2):

In addition, you can use one the various c++ to python wrapping libraries out there, like [swig](http://www.swig.org/) or [boost.python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/python/doc/).
Depending on the complexity and "size" of the c++ library, this might be the more efficient solution.